# C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe is not a valid win32 application

Tags: android

I am trying for getting md5 fingerprint in Android using command prompt ..below is what ever I wrote in command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -key
store "C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh\android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

> Access is denied.

**when I press enter it shows a prompt message that..C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe is not a valid win32 application and when I press OK it shows..**
Access is denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this simple command:

```
keytool -list -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh\android\debug.keystore"
```

when asked for password just press enter.. Tadaaa!! MD5 key is there.